# No overload matches this call. The last overload gave the following error

Tags: typescript, express

collectionRouter.ts:

```
collectionRouter.get(
    '/',
    paginationMiddleware,
    accessTokenMiddleware,
    collectionController.getUserCollections
);
```

paginationMiddleware.ts:

```
export const paginationMiddleware = async (req: RequestWithQuery<PaginationQuery>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    ...
}
```

accessTokenMiddleware.ts:

```
export const accessTokenMiddleware = async (req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    ...
}
```

collectionRouter.ts:

```
async getUserCollections(req: RequestWithQueryAndUser<PaginationQuery>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    ...
}
```

types:

```
export type RequestWithQuery<T> = Request<{}, {}, {}, T>;

export type PaginationQuery = {
    limit: number,
    offset: number
}

export type RequestWithUser = Request & { user: UserTokenInfo };

export type UserTokenInfo = {
    id: number,
    nickname: string
}

export type RequestWithQueryAndUser<T> = RequestWithQuery<T>
    & { user: UserTokenInfo };
```

typescript swears by accessTokenMiddleware:
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type '(req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, PaginationQuery, Record<string, any>>'.
Type '(req: RequestWithUser, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, PaginationQuery, Record<string, any>>'.
Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, PaginationQuery, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'RequestWithUser'.
Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, PaginationQuery, Record<string, any>>' is not assignable to type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
Types of property 'query' are incompatible.
Type 'PaginationQuery' is not assignable to type 'ParsedQs'.
Property 'limit' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]'.

You can try to make generalized types in middleware, but this is a crutch solution for me